# Scrape text from WebBrowser activity using HTML agility pack (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, variables, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to extract fields/text in a WebBrowser activity in Windows form using HTML agility pack. I'm able to scrape text in the background but want to do it in the WebBrowser inside my form.

I tried referencing my HtmlDocument variable to WebBrowser1.Document but it seems I cannot convert it.

This is the error I'm encountering

[image]

And these are the variable type

[image]

Here's my code.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports HtmlAgilityPack


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_load(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox3.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim link As String = TextBox3.Text
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(link)
        Dim web_document As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document

        Dim name As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='details']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h3")
        'if the div is found, print the inner text'
        If Not name Is Nothing Then
            TextBox1.Text = name.InnerText.Trim()

        End If


        Dim customer_number As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='details']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/dl[4]/dd")
        'if the div is found, print the inner text'
        If Not customer_number Is Nothing Then
            TextBox2.Text = customer_number.InnerText.Trim()

        End If

        MessageBox.Show("Doc variable: " + doc.GetType.ToString + Environment.NewLine + "web_document variable: " + web_document.GetType.ToString)

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is [`WebBrowser1.Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document?view=net-5.0) returns a [`Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=net-5.0), which is not the same as [`HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlDocument.cs).

If you want to use HtmlAgilityPack to scrape HTML from a web page in a `WebBrowser` control, you need to get the [`DocumentText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext?view=net-5.0) from the browser control and load it into a new `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` instance like this:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Would you know how can I do this if I have an mshtml.HTMLDocument variable?

Comment: Assuming your `mshtml.HTMLDocument` variable is called `mshtmlDoc`, I would try something like `doc.LoadHtml(mshtmlDoc.body.outerHTML);`